# Use the unique values from a field in one content type as a filter in another content type

Tags: drupal

I need some help with a Drupal views filter.  I'm not a developer but I have been using Drupal for several years.

I have a content type named 'City/Town' that contains several fields including state and county. I'm using this content type as an entity reference field in another content type named 'Project'.

I would like to use a unique value list of States as a filter in a view of Projects.

I've installed the Views Entity Reference Filter (https://www.drupal.org/project/verf) module but I'm only able to access the entity reference title, not any of the fields that are part of the content type.

The project I'm working on is still in design phase so I can change my approach if there is a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the relationship to the reference in views. Then you have access to the fields of the reference for viewing, sorting & filtering.
[image]

Comment: This does work but it's only giving me a text input field which requires the user to know the name and spelling of the information.  Can you suggest an improvement on your answer that would provide the end user a selection list?

Comment: That's a little trickier. You can try the Views Autocomplete Filters module. At best, this will be your solution. Or you can try a custom module. There is a discussion on drupal.org about providing this functionality directly from the core. However, this does not seem to have been implemented yet. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2429699